# Calculate the limit of the limits of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suposse the sequence $x^{n}$ such that

$$x^{n}= (x^{n}_1, x^{n}_2,..., x^{n}_m,...),\quad 0 \leq x^{n}_m \leq 1, \forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$\lim_{m\to \infty} x^{n}_m = 1, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Also, suposse that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x^{n}_m = x_m$. I want to prove that $\lim_{m\to \infty} x_m = 1$. The following array is more explanatory:

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
x^{1}_1 & x^{1}_2 & x^{1}_3 & ... & x^{1}_m & \cdots \to & 1  \\
x^{2}_1 & x^{2}_2 & x^{2}_3 & ... & x^{2}_m & \cdots \to & 1  \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  &     & \vdots  & \vdots  &\vdots &    \\
x^{n}_1 & x^{n}_2 & x^{n}_3 & ... & x^{n}_m & \cdots \to & 1  \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  &     & \vdots  & \vdots  &\vdots &    \\
\downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & ... & \downarrow & \cdots  & \vdots  \\
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & ... & x_m & \cdots \to & ?  \\
 \end{array}

I tried to start with the classical approach: if $\epsilon > 0$, I want find some $m_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$|1 -x_m |< \epsilon, \quad \forall m> m_0$$. But I can not engage the triangular inequality because of the two indices.  I would just like an initial hint. Some ideia or other approach?

Comment: Try $x_m^n=1$ if $m>n$, $x_m^n=0$ if $m\leqslant n$ (and reconsider the result you wish to prove...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to prove
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}x^n_m = \lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n_m\quad\cdots(*)
$$, which is changing the order of the limits, is not true in general. We can see this
by the example $x^n_m = 1_{m>n}$ giving us the result
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}x^n_m = \lim_{n\to\infty}1=1,
$$while
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n_m = \lim_{m\to\infty}0=0.
$$ However, uniform convergence of $x^n_m$ in one of the variables $n$ or $m$ can provide a sufficient condition for $(*)$ to be true. It is a much stronger condition than one of the (or both) limits in $(*)$ does exist. You can see some definitions and further explanation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence, for example.

Comment: you are wrong:  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}x^n_m = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I should have been more careful choosing an example. Maybe I was confused with something like $x^n_m = \frac{m}{n}$.

Comment: In fact, I was trying to prove that the set $\{x \in l^{\infty} : x_m \in [0,1], \lim_{m \to \infty} x_m = 1 \}$ is weakly closed. $x^m \to x$ in the weak topology if $f(x^m) \to f(x)$, for all $f$ in the dual of $l^{\infty}$. Taking $f_m ((x_1, x_2,...x_m,...))= x_m$, I believed that my problem rested on the proposed question.

Comment: Well, actually your set is weakly closed because any convex subset of a Banach space is weakly closed if and only if it is norm closed. Where the problem occurs is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n_m = x^\infty_m$ for all $m\geq 1$ does not mean $x^n \to x^\infty$ (coordinatewise convergence is not sufficient for weak convergence.)  If we identify $l^\infty(\mathbb{N}) \sim C(\beta\mathbb{N})$ where $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is the Stone-Cech compactification, this is almost straightforward.

Comment: You're right. I forgot the basic classes of real analysis. Thank you

Comment: But, How I can prove that the set is norm closed? Is necessary  the use of the Stone-Cech compactification?

Comment: I think I've seen a possibility with the sup norm. I'll try and come back if I can not.

Answer (score 0):

As [already stated](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3032201/11206), it is not true what you want to proof:
\begin{array}{cccccccr}
1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & \to & 0 \\
1& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & \to & 0 \\
1& 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & \to  &0 \\
1& 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & \to  &0 \\
1& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \ldots  & \to & 0 \\
1& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots  & \to & 0 \\
\vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &&\vdots\\
\downarrow & \downarrow &\downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow &\downarrow& &&\downarrow  \\
1& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots  & \to & 1\setminus 0 \\
 \end{array}

Here anothe example where the columns do not converge at all:
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & \to & 0 \\
-2& -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & \to & 0 \\
3& 3 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & \to  &0 \\
-4& -4 & -4 & -4 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & \to  &0 \\
5& 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 0 & \ldots  & \to & 0 \\
-6& -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & \ldots  & \to & 0 \\
\vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &&\vdots\\
\downarrow & \downarrow &\downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow &\downarrow& &&\downarrow  \\
?& ? & ? & ? & ? & ? & \ldots  & \to & ?\setminus 0 \\
 \end{array}

Comment: In fact, I was trying to prove that the set $\{x \in l^{\infty} : x_m \in [0,1], \lim_{m \to \infty} x_m = 1 \}$ is weakly closed. $x^m \to x$ in the weak topology if $f(x^m) \to f(x)$, for all $f$ in the dual of $l^{\infty}$. Taking $f_m ((x_1, x_2,...x_m,...))= x_m$, I believed that my problem rested on the proposed question.